# how to test this type of method using Mockito?

Tags: mockito

```
public double getMinCBQta(long enteCod, long artCod) throws FailureException {
    logger.debug("getMinCBqta() - ENTER");

    double minCBQta = 0;

    final TypedQuery<Double> query = em.createQuery("select NVL(Min(c.qtaCapienza),0) " + "from CapienzaBanco c "
        + "where c.id.enteCod = :ENTECOD AND c.id.artCod = :ARTCOD "
        + "AND c.id.nrPromo = 0 AND c.id.annoPromo = 0 AND c.qtaCapienza!= 0 ", Double.class);

    try {

        query.setParameter(CommonConstants.ENTECOD, enteCod);
        query.setParameter(CommonConstants.ARTCOD, artCod);

        minCBQta = query.getSingleResult();

    } catch (final NoResultException ne) {

        logger.warn("getMinCBQta :No result received from CAPIENZA_BANCO with enetCod " + enteCod + "artCod: " + artCod);

    } catch (final Exception e) {
        logger.error("getMinCBQta : Error Retriving data from CAPIENZA_BANCO  " + e.getMessage());
        throw new FailureException("getMinCBQta : Error Retriving data from CAPIENZA_BANCO " + e);
    }

    logger.debug("getMinCBqta()" + " EXIT");

    return minCBQta;
}
```

Comment: There's not much to test there. All you can do is mock the EntityManager and then verify that the correct methods were called. You can also test the exception handling to some extent.

Comment: ok. i will try.  @Florian Schaetz

Comment: Agreeing with Florian, I'd say that this is a much better case to test against an in-memory database. Create a table, add some rows, call the method, and see if it returns what you want it to return.